# CMake Cant find CryptoPP with find_package

Tags: c++, cmake, crypto++

I've installed C++ library "Crypto++" using `sudo apt install libcrypto++-dev`

I find lib using this command: `find_package(CryptoPP REQUIRED)`

But CMake cant find it for some reason, and print this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:40 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindCryptoPP.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "CryptoPP",
  but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "CryptoPP" with any
  of the following names:

    CryptoPPConfig.cmake
    cryptopp-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "CryptoPP" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "CryptoPP_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "CryptoPP" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

I also tried all names like CryptoPP, and etc. It didnt work.

Comment: In the package [libcrypto++-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/amd64/libcrypto++-dev/filelist) there is no `.cmake` file. So, unless you ship your project with appropriate `Find*.cmake` script, you cannot find this installation via `find_package`.

Answer (score 2):

Three seconds of googling shows that the CryptoPP folks [decided](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/249#issuecomment-412829700) to stop supporting CMake themselves.

The community-supported CMake build stuff is now [here](https://github.com/abdes/cryptopp-cmake). As the build instructions go, fetch it and then you can link your target(s) to `cryptopp`.

Alternatively, you can try your luck with the pkgconfig file that seems to ship with that package:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(Cryptopp REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET libcrypto++)
target_link_libraries(your_application PUBLIC PkgConfig::Cryptopp)
```